# how can I verify a mock was called with a param with specific fields' values?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I write a UT using mockito mock.

I want to verify the mock was called with this param: `MyObject obj` where obj = `{ name =... , value = 9}`

I want to verify the mock was called with param which has value 9.

how would you do this?

I don't want to override `equals(..)` in `myObject`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These is a built-in matcher: `hasProperty`

```
assertThat(externalPois, Matchers.hasItem(Matchers.<ExternalPoi>hasProperty("id", is(5))));
```

Answer (score 0):

mockito has ArgumentMatcher interface:

```
 class IsListOfTwoElements extends ArgumentMatcher<List> {
     public boolean matches(Object list) {
         return ((List) list).size() == 2;
     }
 }

 List mock = mock(List.class);

 when(mock.addAll(argThat(new IsListOfTwoElements()))).thenReturn(true);
```